# openStdin() vs process.stdin.on('data' ,()=> {})

Tags: asynchronous, synchronous

**what is the difference** ,
as there are so many way to take input and easy to make a begineer bite the dust

what i notice both of these below 1 and 2 is asynchronous by nature they dont wait for next line of input all the input you want to give , just give on single line (unlike prompt-sync)

1.

```
var stdin = process.openStdin();
stdin.addListener("data", function(d) { // d a object
    console.log("you entered: [" + 
        d.toString().trim() + "]");
  });
```

---

2. 

```
process.stdin.on('data' , (e) => {           // e is also object 
    
    // process.stdout.write(e)
     console.log("" + e)                   // string  + object  = string  ; XD
})
```

both of these above method of is worst then why dont we use prompt-sync , is there any hidden advantage of using these two  ,ok  this my **2nd question** though

describe the concept , which one is sync which one is async , which one to use in which situation